# Remover BRs despues de resultado de scrape con beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

de nuevo molestando, estoy haciendo una especie de buscador de rank de personajes de un juego. Hasta ahora va todo bien hasta el momento en que al arrojar el resultado de una de las busquedas e imprimirlo, me deforma el output porque tiene BRs introducidos en el código html.

Este es mi código:

```
# Importamos las librerias
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import os
import re

 # Capturamos la url 
html = urlopen('http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=Elfwinny')
url = "http://maplestory.nexon.net/rankings/world-ranking/reboot-(na)?pageIndex=1&character_name=Elfwinny"
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 # Capturamos el hml de la pagina web y creamos un objeto Response
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

#Sacamos toda la información de la tabla de rank proporcionada:

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
avatar = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.png')})
job = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.gif')})
htnm_migration_table = soup.find("table", {'class':''})
tbody = htnm_migration_table.find('tbody')
trs = htnm_migration_table.find('tr')
td = htnm_migration_table.find_all('td')

print("Avatar de ElfWinny: " + avatar[2]["src"])
print("Nickname: " + td[2].text)
print("Job: " + job[0]["src"])
print("Nivel: " + td[5].text)
```

Justo en print("Nivel: " + td[5].text) es el que me deforma la linea pues me copia el contenido de el TD como tal que es el siguiente:

```
232                   <br>                                                         (61857388727)<br>
```

Además de esta duda, quisiera saber si hay manera tambien, de aislar o imprimir por separado ambos numeros (el 232 en un print, y el (61857388727) en otro print).

Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes dividir el contenido usando split(), y obtener cada parte como si fuera un array:

```
td[5].text.split('\n')[0] //primera linea
td[5].text.split('\n')[1] //segunda linea
```

Si quieres remover espacios habría que quitarlos con `replace()`

```
td[5].text.split('\n')[0].replace(/ /g,'')
```